# How to skip running scalafmt on test code?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

Scalafmt [official plugin](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.geirsson" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "1.5.1")
```

doesn't seem to offer any setting to disable running the checks on test code. There is an unofficial [neo-sbt-scalafmt](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/neo-sbt-scalafmt) that has a setting `scalafmtTestOnCompile` but it seems not maintained anymore.

Is there a way to skip running scalafmt on test code using the official plugin?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your scalafmt.conf

```
project.excludeFilters = [
  com.xxx.test
]
```

Comment: Actually, I found out that the test folder is excluded by default. Besides, you’re assuming a special package for test code, that often isn’t the case.